# Replace chunk name with module name in angular 4 lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular4-router, angular-router-loader

I'm using angular-cli-1.6.3 for bundling my project.
I try to rename lazy loaded chunk name into valid module name. But it is not working. Code snippet given below,

```
{
  path: 'lazy',
  loadChildren: './lazy/module#LazyModule?chunkName=LazyModule'
}
```

Comment: why are you using `?chunkName=LazyModule`? where did you got that from?

Comment: I saw some sample. But now i removed that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you should be using `-nc` flag

```
ng build --aot -nc
```

or

```
ng build --aot --named-chunks
```

Update 1 : Based on Comment

to remove the hash numbers set the `--output-hashing` to false as below

```
ng build --aot --nc --output-hashing=false
```

**[Documentation Link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)**

Comment: Throwing error like: ERROR in Error: LazyModule?chunkName=LazyModule is not an NgModule

Comment: it simply created a file like "module.ebc4664b446ca766a851.chunk.js". But i want module name as file name or custom name. Do needful

Comment: whats is the name of the module ?

Comment: Module name: "LazyModule"

Comment: `lazy.module.chunk.js` will be the file name created

Comment: no it created like this only "module.ebc4664b446ca766a851.chunk.js". What to do? Im using angular-cli-1.6.3

Comment: what is the name of the file you have? it will be based on that!

Comment: File name: module.ts

Comment: Rename that too lazy.module.ts

Comment: Yeah Its worked.. "lazy.module.e7e62921c478fc93d386.chunk.js". But is there any way to remove that hash code in the file name? Reason is, in future if i changed anything in that particular module, ill compile and replace the particular file alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my time.

Comment: But i didnt find any documentation like, that file name is related to chunk name. If you have any link please updated that in your Answer.

Comment: Hey everyone! The chunks have hashes for a reason. What if you update your app and people still have it open? They'll get the OLD compatible hashed file instead of loading a new file with the same name that may not be compatible. If you have files on a CDN they may get cached too - so having unique filenames per version is much safer.

Answer (score 5):

```
 ng build --namedChunks=true --outputHashing=none --vendorChunk=true
```

- `namedChunks` Use file name for lazy loaded chunks
- `output-hashing` Define the output filename cache-busting hashing mode.
- `vendorChunk` Use a separate bundle containing only vendor libraries.